# .htaccess How to set expiry time for downloads?

Tags: .htaccess, download, webserver, browser-cache, cache-control

I don't want the browser to cache my **exe** (setup/installer) files. One hour is more than enough. Is this a good .htaccess setup?

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload "access 1 hour"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Comment: Make it `ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload "access plus 1 hours"`

Comment: Offering an executable file for download... ***shudder***

Comment: @arkascha - This is how people do it on modern & user-friendly (GUI) operation systems. Anyway, I don't know how one could otherwise deliver a product. If not as exe, then what? As printed binary characters on paper?

Comment: @anubhava - Could you shortly describe the difference between "access plus x" and "access x"

Comment: Ok. I have found the difference: none :)     http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html

Comment: Indeed `plus` is optional keyword but is very important functionality to allow us to use relative data/time from current timestamp.

Comment: You are absoutely right, this is how it is typically done today. However it is also true that this is one of the major points how malware is spread, since the user has absolutely no way to check whether what he downloads actually is what he wants to download and whether that binary has been compromised or not. That is a very real thread that is actively used. There certainly are alternatives to this. But I agree with you that what you are doing is in line with what is typically done today.

Comment: > There certainly are alternatives to this. So, what would be the alternative then? :)